# Gnome tweak tool not installing

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I tried to install gnome-tweak tool but its says

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gnome-tweak-tool: Depends: python (< 2.8) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed

what should i do to install gnome-tweak tool ?

Comment: How did you try to install it? On which OS and version number?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the depending python version from Synaptic Package manager.Gnome Tweaks depends on that, as your message clarifies.